# What is thread hopping and when is it necessary?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Saw the term 'thread-hopping' while reading some documentation, I didn't find a good description after a few minutes of googling. So as per title, what is thread hopping and when is it necessary?

Context - I came across the term while reading source code https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/78c250bf4429501db4e285a4840f0b934797d5a7/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/schedulers/ExecutorScheduler.java#L37

Comment: This question seems to be receiving a lot of downvotes and I'm not sure why. If you downvoted this question, can you help explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: It would help to add some context to your question. Thread hopping probably isn't a term used in a conventional way.

Comment: The context is I came across it reading source code of https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/78c250bf4429501db4e285a4840f0b934797d5a7/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/schedulers/ExecutorScheduler.java#L37

Comment: Also, it can't be that obscure if there are so many instances of this term in source code comments, and the deleted answer is actually pretty good, I would have accepted it https://github.com/search?p=1&q=thread-hopping&ref=searchresults&type=Code

Comment: im guessing that it means you can't guarantee to be on the same thread.

Comment: the exact JCIP reference is section 9.3, page 197.

Comment: I would have upvoted the deleted answer if it was not deleted.

Comment: @NathanHughes, there's no such thing as voting to undelete, at least at the present time.

Comment: @Alex: oh right, you don't get that until 20K.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is the phenomenon of having a lot of tasks/jobs/runnables being executed by an executor service which is backed by a pool of threads with unknown internal queueing mechanisms.

In such cases there might not be a way to predict which job is running in which of the pooled threads and special attention has to be paid to communication between threads, ownership, ..

In a way the execution of tasks hops from thread to thread. This is not strictly necessary, one could implement affinity to threads, but it's often difficult to avoid, so one has to be careful.

I got my knowledge about this from googling for some time. Therefore I make it community wiki.